# Problems with 14.04.2 LTS and Nvidia GT218 and nouveau

Tags: nvidia

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.2 server install to which I have added Unity (`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`) so that I can get a couple terminals on the monitor.  I'm seeing a number of errors in the syslog/dmesg and not getting anything to display.

The same machine boots Fedora20 and Windows2012 (different partitions on the same HDD) fine.  Can anyone point me in a direction to fix this?

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

below are relevant sections from dmesg, the complete dmesg can be found here http://pastebin.com/ufmkavQd

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-45-generic (buildd@phianna) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-45.74-generic 3.13.11-ckt13)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=8dfe8b36-052b-4dad-a0f6-ccf245c77b72 ro splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007d954fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d955000-0x000000007d9d1fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d9d2000-0x000000007da34fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007da35000-0x000000007dcfefff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007dcff000-0x000000007f2fcfff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f2fd000-0x000000007f348fff] type 20
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f349000-0x000000007f369fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f36a000-0x000000007f36bfff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f36c000-0x000000007f36cfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f36d000-0x000000007f3f2fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f3f3000-0x000000007f7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed3ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000107fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x7da35000  ACPI=0x7da35000  SMBIOS=0xf04d0  MPS=0xfd5a0 
....
[   20.825386] fb: conflicting fb hw usage nouveaufb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[   20.825402] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   20.828553] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:0b:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x0a8180b1
[   20.828556] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:0b:00.0] Chipset: GT218 (NVA8)
[   20.828557] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:0b:00.0] Family : NV50
[   20.831615] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:0b:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image...
[   21.001438] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:0b:00.0] ... appears to be valid
[   21.001440] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:0b:00.0] using image from PRAMIN
[   21.001538] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:0b:00.0] BIT signature found
[   21.001540] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:0b:00.0] version 70.18.76.00.05
[   21.002754] nouveau 0000:0b:00.0: irq 99 for MSI/MSI-X
[   21.002770] nouveau  [     PMC][0000:0b:00.0] MSI interrupts enabled
[   21.002808] nouveau W[     PFB][0000:0b:00.0] memory controller reports 256 MiB VRAM
[   21.002816] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:0b:00.0] RAM type: DDR3
[   21.002817] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:0b:00.0] RAM size: 256 MiB
[   21.002818] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:0b:00.0]    ZCOMP: 480 tags
[   21.012826] nouveau  [    VOLT][0000:0b:00.0] GPU voltage: 1050000uv
....
[   21.263238] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): em2: link is not ready
[   22.291729] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:0b:00.0] FAN control: none / external
[   22.291738] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:0b:00.0] fan management: automatic
[   22.291743] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:0b:00.0] internal sensor: yes
[   22.291779] dmar: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[   22.291783] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:0b:00.0] 03: core 135 MHz shader 270 MHz memory 135 MHz
[   22.291786] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:0b:00.0] 07: core 405 MHz shader 810 MHz memory 324 MHz
[   22.291788] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:0b:00.0] 0f: core 520 MHz shader 1230 MHz memory 500 MHz
[   22.291790] dmar: INTR-REMAP: Request device [[00:1e.0] fault index 47
[   22.291790] INTR-REMAP:[fault reason 38] Blocked an interrupt request due to source-id verification failure
[   22.291852] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:0b:00.0] --: core 405 MHz shader 810 MHz memory 405 MHz
[   22.292079] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 32972322 kiB
[   22.292080] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[   22.292082] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   22.292085] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   22.292093] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 256 MiB
[   22.292094] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[   22.292098] nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
[   22.292100] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[   22.292102] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 00: 01000302 00020030
[   22.292104] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 01: 02000300 00000000
[   22.292105] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 02: 02022362 00020010
[   22.292106] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 03: 01011310 00000000
[   22.292108] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 00: 00001030
[   22.292110] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 01: 00000100
[   22.292111] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 02: 00002261
[   22.364638] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   22.364639] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[   22.445202] nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[   22.519570] nouveau  [     DRM] allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x70000, bo ffff88102371bc00
[   22.519618] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
[   24.521912] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   24.986238] nouveau E[     DRM] GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon
[   25.057286] nouveau 0000:0b:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[   25.057287] nouveau 0000:0b:00.0: registered panic notifier
[   25.057301] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.2 20120801 for 0000:0b:00.0 on minor 0
[   25.057420] hda_intel: Disabling MSI
[   25.057434] hda-intel 0000:0b:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[   25.057487] hda-intel 0000:0b:00.1: Disabling 64bit DMA
[   25.058345] e1000e: em2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   25.058665] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): em2: link becomes ready
[   25.070415] hda-intel 0000:0b:00.1: Enable delay in RIRB handling
[   25.887260] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0a:04.0/0000:0b:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[   25.887350] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0a:04.0/0000:0b:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[   25.887397] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0a:04.0/0000:0b:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[   25.887443] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0a:04.0/0000:0b:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[   32.075418] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
...
[   57.801179] cgroup: "memory" requires setting use_hierarchy to 1 on the root.
[  171.996854] nouveau E[Xorg[1354]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1354]]
[  187.011255] nouveau E[Xorg[1354]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1354]]
[  189.014073] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[1354]] unload timeout
[  272.909660] nouveau E[Xorg[1808]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1808]]
[  287.924058] nouveau E[Xorg[1808]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1808]]
[  289.926928] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[1808]] unload timeout
[  373.854495] nouveau E[Xorg[1999]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1999]]
[  388.868897] nouveau E[Xorg[1999]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1999]]
[  390.871773] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[1999]] unload timeout
[  474.771303] nouveau E[Xorg[2299]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2299]]
[  489.785704] nouveau E[Xorg[2299]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2299]]
[  491.791843] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[2299]] unload timeout
[  575.704127] nouveau E[Xorg[2491]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2491]]
[  590.718530] nouveau E[Xorg[2491]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2491]]
[  592.721335] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[2491]] unload timeout
[  676.664977] nouveau E[Xorg[2671]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2671]]
[  691.679380] nouveau E[Xorg[2671]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2671]]
[  693.682205] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[2671]] unload timeout
[  777.581788] nouveau E[Xorg[2884]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2884]]
[  792.596189] nouveau E[Xorg[2884]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[2884]]
[  794.599004] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[2884]] unload timeout
[  878.538636] nouveau E[Xorg[3095]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3095]]
[  893.553038] nouveau E[Xorg[3095]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3095]]
[  895.555915] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3095]] unload timeout
[  979.455445] nouveau E[Xorg[3305]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3305]]
[  994.469845] nouveau E[Xorg[3305]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3305]]
[  996.472720] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3305]] unload timeout
[ 1080.388267] nouveau E[Xorg[3467]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3467]]
[ 1095.402669] nouveau E[Xorg[3467]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3467]]
[ 1097.405482] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3467]] unload timeout
[ 1181.257031] nouveau E[Xorg[3630]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3630]]
[ 1196.271432] nouveau E[Xorg[3630]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3630]]
[ 1198.277518] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3630]] unload timeout
[ 1282.201868] nouveau E[Xorg[3791]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3791]]
[ 1297.228280] nouveau E[Xorg[3791]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3791]]
[ 1299.244281] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3791]] unload timeout
[ 1369.919351] nouveau E[   PDISP][0000:0b:00.0][0xc000857c][ffff8810233b2f80] channel stalled
[ 1385.168641] nouveau E[Xorg[3980]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3980]]
[ 1400.195056] nouveau E[Xorg[3980]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[3980]]
[ 1402.212168] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[3980]] unload timeout
[ 1486.177540] nouveau E[Xorg[4142]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4142]]
[ 1501.203952] nouveau E[Xorg[4142]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4142]]
[ 1503.221921] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[4142]] unload timeout
[ 1587.174425] nouveau E[Xorg[4353]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4353]]
[ 1602.204844] nouveau E[Xorg[4353]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4353]]
[ 1604.223725] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[4353]] unload timeout
[ 1688.135276] nouveau E[Xorg[4540]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4540]]
[ 1703.165691] nouveau E[Xorg[4540]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4540]]
[ 1705.185315] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[4540]] unload timeout
[ 1789.084117] nouveau E[Xorg[4734]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4734]]
[ 1804.114531] nouveau E[Xorg[4734]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4734]]
[ 1806.135068] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[4734]] unload timeout
[ 1890.052973] nouveau E[Xorg[4944]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4944]]
[ 1905.083389] nouveau E[Xorg[4944]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[4944]]
[ 1907.105547] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:0b:00.0] channel 3 [Xorg[4944]] unload timeout
```

Comment: I was givinWelcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: **Why are you triple-booting a server?** Because the answer for a server is completely different then the answer for a desktop....

Comment: Does it really matter that I'm triple booting it. No. It boots Ubuntu fine, just not Graphics.  If you really need to know, I have it triple booting (and maybe more to come) because the company I work for has a driver and some tools, which need to be tested on every operating system we support.

Comment: There you go: I would have told you to remove the GPU from the server...  Now I'm telling you to install the desktop OS.  That is meant to be run with a GUI, the server isn't...  But you can!  **;-)**  See above.